# how to horizontally align icons with different sizes in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to align icons horizontally like this in a row, with `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly` and `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center`.

The result I am getting is something like this
[image: result I am getting]

But I am trying to get a result like this.

[image: desired result]

my code:

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            IconButton(onPressed: ()=>{}, icon: Icon(Icons.home_sharp, color: Color(0xFFf1a40a), size: 40,)),
            IconButton(onPressed: ()=>{}, icon: Icon(Icons.search_sharp, color: Color(0xFFe7e5d3), size: 40,)),
            IconButton(onPressed: ()=>{}, icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outlined, color: Color(0xFFfad974), size: 60,)),
            IconButton(onPressed: ()=>{}, icon: Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Color(0xFFe7e5d3), size: 40,)),
            IconButton(onPressed: ()=>{}, icon: Icon(Icons.people_alt_sharp, color: Color(0xFFe7e5d3), size: 40,)),
          ],
        )
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Use `iconSize` on `IconButton` instead of `size` of `Icon`

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    IconButton(
      iconSize: 40,
        onPressed: () => {},
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.home_sharp,
          color: Color(0xFFf1a40a),
          
        )),
    IconButton(
      iconSize: 40,
        onPressed: () => {},
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.search_sharp,
          color: Color(0xFFe7e5d3),
          
        )),
    IconButton(
        onPressed: () => {},
        iconSize: 60,
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.add_circle_outlined,
          color: Color(0xFFfad974),
        )),
    IconButton(
      iconSize: 40,
        onPressed: () => {},
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.notifications,
          color: Color(0xFFe7e5d3),
          
        )),
    IconButton(
      iconSize: 40,
        onPressed: () => {},
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.people_alt_sharp,
          color: Color(0xFFe7e5d3),
          
        )),
  ],
),
```

[image]

Comment: use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,` if needed for your case

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Answer (score 2):

You should give the size and the color to the `IconButton`, not the `Icon`. Like

```
  children: [
    IconButton(onPressed: ()=>{}, color: Color(0xFFf1a40a), iconSize: 40, icon: Icon(Icons.home_sharp)),
    IconButton(onPressed: ()=>{}, color: Color(0xFFe7e5d3), iconSize: 40, icon: Icon(Icons.search_sharp)),
    IconButton(onPressed: ()=>{}, color: Color(0xFFfad974), iconSize: 60, icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outlined)),
    IconButton(onPressed: ()=>{}, color: Color(0xFFe7e5d3), iconSize: 40, icon: Icon(Icons.notifications)),
    IconButton(onPressed: ()=>{}, color: Color(0xFFe7e5d3), iconSize: 40, icon: Icon(Icons.people_alt_sharp)),
  ],
```

From `IconButton` documentation:

```
  /// The icon to display inside the button.
  ///
  /// The [Icon.size] and [Icon.color] of the icon is configured automatically
  /// based on the [iconSize] and [color] properties of _this_ widget using an
  /// [IconTheme] and therefore should not be explicitly given in the icon
  /// widget.
  ///
  /// This property must not be null.
  ///
  /// See [Icon], [ImageIcon].
  final Widget icon;
```